# Chi-square analog for context-dependent distributions

Tags: distributions, probability, chi-squared-test, predictor

Lets imagine that we have some experiments. Each experiment may result in one of the outcomes: A, B, C. So we have probabilities distribution for each experiment $P_A, P_B, P_C$ which is context-dependent.

E.g.:

1. $Context_1 \Rightarrow \{P_A^1, P_B^1, P_C^1\},$ experimental outcome is A
2. $Context_2 \Rightarrow \{P_A^2, P_B^2, P_C^2\},$ experimental outcome is B
3. $Context_3 \Rightarrow \{P_A^3, P_B^3, P_C^3\},$ experimental outcome is A
4. $Context_4 \Rightarrow \{P_A^4, P_B^4, P_C^4\},$ experimental outcome is C

This probabilities are calculated by some function $F:Context\rightarrow \{P_A, P_B, P_C\}$  
I want to estimate an absolute trust rate of this function. In other words, I want to be able to say "we can trust this function on 86%" like we do when we deal with Pearson's chi-square test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How many contexts do you have and how many data points per context?

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of contexts and only one data point per context in common case.

Comment: I am not sure that you can do statistics on the player's strategy without more data. Either you have enough data and you can train a machine learning algorithm, or you don't and you have to do assumptions on the underlying model you want to use.

Comment: Well you can try but I would not be very confident with the results. Do you want to invest real money into this strategy?

Comment: @fRed I have machine learning algorithm, but I'm not sure about its reliability. No real money, this is an academic research.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need a HMM to do that.
Have you read
Lawrence R. Rabiner (February 1989). ["A tutorial on Hidden Markov Models and selected applications in speech recognition"](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf)

There are a few examples of models parameters discovery on page 259.

The question is how do you plan to update the probabilites? Maybe you can use a kind of success ratio? (if the player has not managed to win much recently using one of the 3 strategies, he may use it less and try more the two others...)

Comment: Sorry now that you have reformulated your question, my answer is not really appropriate

Comment: That's ok! The first formulation was not clear enough, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question (and falling into the same misunderstanding as fRed despite your explanation), in which case I apologize.  It seems to me like you are saying you already know the various P_A, P_B, and P_C values for each context.  I assume P_A + P_B + P_C = 1? Given those priors and the actual outcome you want to characterize the accuracy of the already established P values?

One approach might be simulation.  Given the various P_A, P_B, and P_C values for each context you could generate guesses from the model at the probabilities indicated by each P value and then compare that to the obtained data.  Averaging over many simulations you should get a sense of the average hit-rate of the model.